# Stop Processing Of ASP.Net Web Form on Opening an Exe

Tags: asp.net, .net, executable

In my ASP.net application, i have to open a EXE on click of button. When the EXE is open, User should not be allowed to perform any action on the web form, i.e. the exe should behave like a modal popup. I am using the current code to open and return value from EXE.

```
        Dim p As Process

    p = Process.Start("D:\VS2010Projects\SignatureCaptureWindows\bin\Debug\SignatureCaptureWindows.exe")

    p.WaitForExit()

    If (Not p.ExitCode.Equals(0)) Then
        Response.Write("Image Successfully saved in Database with ID = " + p.ExitCode.ToString())
        DisplaySavedImage(p.ExitCode)
    End If
```

The Exe is opening fine and returning the correct value. However, the user is able to perform action on the web form when the exe is open...

What will be the best way to handle such a scenario ??

Comment: If you want to completely block the user from interacting with the website while this EXE is running on the server, then you are IMHO asking for trouble.  What happens if something fails on the server, and the user is left with a completely unusable website?

Comment: @freefaller The exe will be used to capture the user's signature.. Once the signature is captured, then the form can be processed further

Comment: It doesn't matter what the EXE is doing, it is the "blocking" of all user-interaction on the browser that is the issue. Aristos has given a very good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its impossible to do the way you won it. From the moment the user send a submit, or try to open the page, and on code behind you run this exe, then user is wait for the results - in this time you can not make the user to not do anything else - you can not lock the browser, user can close it, reload it, open again the same page, etc.

What you can do is to lock this process using `Mutex` and not allow to run again if all ready run it.

Mutex on msdn with example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx